# General error handler: If any error in UserForm other than msgBox: Err.Description

Tags: excel, vba, userform

As soon as I get an error in my code, I want a msgbox to open. I have intentionally built errors into my code, but a msgbox does not appear, MicroSoft Visual Basic for Applications opens.

How can I get my msgbox to appear? Also, how can I also use the query for complete UserForm? There is the UserForm_Error function, but is it meant for that?

The intentional error is that there is no DataBaseTest, which I want to trigger this error:

> Error: variable not defined

```
Private Sub ConnectCheck()
    ' Versuchen, eine Verbindung zur Datenbank herzustellen
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim connStr As String
    connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & PathDB & ";Jet OLEDB:DatabaseTest Password=" & PasswordDB & ";" 'no DatabaseTest intentionally entered a mistake
    
    Dim conn As Object
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    

    conn.Open connStr

    
    If conn.State = 1 Then
        ' Verbunden
        LabelConnect.Caption = "Connected"
        LabelConnect.Font = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Else

'        LabelConnect.Caption = "Not Connected"
'        LabelConnect.Font = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
    

    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description
    

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to make it so people cannot click the "debug" button when you get an error? There is no way to do that.

Comment: yeah, trying to do this. Oh okay, sad :/

Comment: I mean instead of debuging windows. Should come only a msgbox where says the error and people just say okay and close the window and the userform keeps running

Comment: Maybe you mean you want to put a `Resume Next` after the `MsgBox` line in your error handler? Keep in mind if you do that, you will very possibly get more errors.

Comment: No, for example, if i write LabelTest.Caption = "test" but LabelTest doesnt exists and after i run the code, ill get a window with variable not defined and can click debug or close. But dont want that the window pop ups. Instead the "standard" debuging windows ill just a msjbox where the error is written in this case variable not defined. And the user can only click okay and they wont see the visual basic applications where is the codes are. On my code in my question it doesnt cover such error like variable not definied

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be referring to a compile-time error.  However, the `On Error` statement only handles a run-time error.  So you should manually compile your code before trying to run it.  This way you'll avoid a compile-time error when running it.

First, make sure that you have the following statement at the very top of your module before any procedures.  This will force you to declare all variables.  So, if you try to use an undeclared variable, you'll get a compile-time error.

```
Option Explicit
```

Then manually compile your code, and fix any errors that pop-up.  Once any errors are fixed and your workbook is saved, any errors that pop-up will occur a run-time, which your `On Error` statement will catch.

```
Visual Basic Editor (Alt+F11) >> Debug >> Compile VBAProject
```

Comment: Hello, its already selected. I don't think I was able to express myself properly. It comes debuging message and when I click on it the visual basic applications opens but since the UserForm is then used by other users, I do not want that if there is an error debugging and then visual applications opens but only msgbox with err.description